# passing html through js using fs.readFileSync and buf.toString

Tags: javascript, html, heroku

hi i'm trying to push code from my html file into my javascript file using buffers, toString, and readFileSync. I have a javacript file named index.js and a html file named index.html. This is the error on my site :

```
https://secret-ocean-5221.herokuapp.com/
```

This is my JS:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(fs.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
var buf = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync("index.html"), "utf-8");
response.send(buf.toString);
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'));
});
```

my HTML simply says:

```
Welcome to my site.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
(1) I did not push my html file into my github repo
(2) My code was wrong here is the right code :

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data){
    response.send(data.toString());
    });
});

 app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the toString method, only passing it in. Change to:

```
response.send(buf.toString());
```

Also, static is a property of express, not fs.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

With that, assuming your index.html file is in public, you don't need the fs.readFileSync at all.

It would also be more idiomatic to call readFile and use the node callback so it is non-blocking.

```
app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    fs.readFile("index.html", function (err, fileBuffer) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err); // Tell express to handle errors
        }
        response.send(fileBuffer.toString());
    });
});
```